# Recommendations for workflow when debugging Python scripts employing multiprocessing?

Tags: debugging, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I use the Spyder IDE. Usually, when I am running non-parallelized scripts, I tend to debug using `print` statements. Depending on which statements are printed (or not), I can see where errors are occurring.

For example:

```
print "Started while loop..."
doWhileLoop = False
while doWhileLoop == True:
    print "Doing something important!"
    time.sleep(5)
print "Finished while loop..."
```

Above, I am missing a line that changes `doWhileLoop` to `False` at some point, so I will be stuck perpetually in the while loop, but my `print` statements let me see where it is in my code that I have hung up.

However, when running scripts that are parallelized, I get no output to the console until after the process has finished. Normally, what I do in this case is attempt to debug with a single process (i.e. temporarily deparallelize the program by running only one task, for instance), but currently, I am dealing with an error that seems to occur *only* when I am running more than one task.

So, I am having trouble figuring out what this error is using my usual methods -- how should I change my usual debugging practice in order to efficiently debug scripts employing multiprocessing?

Comment: Debugging parallel things is hard.  You kind of just have to do it on a case-by-case basis.  As for your `print` statements not printing until the process is done, that's probably Spyder doing some stdout buffering that doesn't otherwise happen.  You can do `sys.stdout.flush()` after every print statement, or use a different environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @roippi said, debugging parallel things is hard.  Another tool is using `logging` over `print`.  Logging gives you severity, timestamps, and most importantly *which* process is doing something.

Example code:

```
import logging, multiprocessing, Queue

def myproc(arg):
    return arg*2

def worker(inqueue, outqueue):
    mylog = multiprocessing.get_logger()
    mylog.info('start')
    for job in iter(inqueue.get, 'STOP'):
        mylog.info('got %s', job)
        try:
            outqueue.put( myproc(job), timeout=1 )
        except Queue.Full:
            mylog.error('queue full!')

    mylog.info('done')

def executive(inqueue):
    total = 0
    mylog = multiprocessing.get_logger()
    for num in iter(inqueue.get, 'STOP'):
        total += num
        mylog.info('got {}\ttotal{}', job, total)

logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(
    level=logging.INFO,
)
logger.info('setup')

inqueue, outqueue = multiprocessing.Queue(), multiprocessing.Queue()
if 0:                           # debug 'queue full!' issues
    outqueue = multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize=1)
# prefill with 3 jobs
for num in range(3):
    inqueue.put(num)
# signal end of jobs
inqueue.put('STOP')

worker_p = multiprocessing.Process(
    target=worker, args=(inqueue, outqueue),
    name='worker',
)
worker_p.start()

worker_p.join()

logger.info('done')
```

Example output:

```
[INFO/MainProcess] setup
[INFO/worker] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/worker] start
[INFO/worker] got 0
[INFO/worker] got 1
[INFO/worker] got 2
[INFO/worker] done
[INFO/worker] process shutting down
[INFO/worker] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/MainProcess] done
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
```